# fabricjs restore modifications

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am creating app with fabricjs where user can drag pets to the canvas which have background image and do modifications like rotating, scaling, etc.

When I wanted to change/toggle background of the canvas to any other image, all images already dropped inside canvas should be restored to the state when they are dropped first time to the canvas (its size, position, angle, etc). Can I save state of each object/image so that I can restore it when background changes, and how to do it?

here is code i am using to change the background

```
$("#change-bg").on("click", function(){
        canvas.setBackgroundImage("assets/images/sofa.jpg", function(){
            canvas.renderAll();
            // restore all objets states
            // ... don't have any idea yet
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this for a solution:

Whenever a new object is added to the canvas, export the canvas data to JSON:

```
    savedposition = canvas.toJSON();
```

In your function to change the BG, just load the savedposition JSON string back on to the canvas, then render the background:

```
    canvas.loadFromJSON(savedposition,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

There's a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/sbT3d/

Comment: i've found my own way doing this, however i will keep your idea if my idea goes wrong. thanks a lot